# Function is bound, but still getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, binding, this, semantic-ui-react, react-state

I am essentially following this [example](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu/#types-pointing)(the second one) on Semantic-UI-React exactly, except I am passing props down two levels. I get the default active state to be 'home' but when I click any link I get this error:

[image]

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
 Button,
 Container,
 Icon,
 Menu,
 Responsive,
 Segment,
 Sidebar,
 Visibility,
} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { logInUser, logOutUser } from '../../store'

import Link from 'next/link';


var comparator;
const GenericIsUserLoggedInLink = React.memo(({ isHomeButton, isLoggedIn, logOutUser, route, anchorText, mobile, name, active, handleItemClick }) => {

 comparator = (prevProps, nextProps) => {

  if (prevProps.isHomeButton !== nextProps.setProps.isHomeButton) {
   return true;
  }
  if (prevProps.isLoggedIn !== nextProps.setProps.isLoggedIn) {
   return true;
  }
  if (prevProps.mobile !== nextProps.setProps.mobile) {
   return true;
  }
  if (prevProps.active !== nextProps.setProps.active) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

 function currentNav(route, name, active, handleItemClick) {

  console.log("handleItemClick ", handleItemClick);
  console.log("active ", active);
  console.log("name ", name);

  return (
    <Link href={route}>
      <Menu.Item
       key={name}
       name={name}
       active={active === name}
       onClick={handleItemClick} // Should I be passing name into here? i.e. handleItemClick(name)
       >
      </Menu.Item>
     </Link>
  );

 }

 if (isHomeButton) {
  return currentNav(route, name, active, handleItemClick)
 }
 if (isLoggedIn) {
  if (anchorText === undefined) {
   return <Link href="/"><a onClick={() => logOutUser()}>Log out!</a></Link>
  }
  else if (mobile) {
   return currentNav(route, name, active, handleItemClick)
  }
  else if (!(mobile)) {
   return currentNav(route, name, active, handleItemClick)
  }

  else if (anchorText) {
   return <Link href={route}><a>{anchorText}</a></Link>
  }
 } else {
  if (route === "/login") {
   return <Link href="/login"><a>Log in!</a></Link>
  }
  return null
 }
}, comparator);



class DesktopContainer extends Component {
 state = {activeItem : 'home'}

 handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })


 logOutUser = () => {
  const { logOutUser } = this.props
  logOutUser()
 }

 render() {
  const { GenericHeadingComponent, children, getWidth, isLoggedIn, logOutUser } = this.props


  const { fixed, activeItem } = this.state

  return (
   <Responsive getWidth={getWidth} minWidth={Responsive.onlyTablet.minWidth}>

       <Container>

        <GenericIsUserLoggedInLink
         isHomeButton={true}
         route="/"
         name='home'
         active={activeItem}
         handleItemClick={this.handleItemClick}
         mobile={false}
        />

        <GenericIsUserLoggedInLink
         isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
         route="/profile"
         anchorText="Profile"
         name='profile'
         active={activeItem}
         handleItemClick={this.handleItemClick}
         mobile={false}
        />

        <GenericIsUserLoggedInLink
         isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
         route="/dashboard"
         anchorText="Dashboard"
         name='dashboard'
         active={activeItem}
         handleItemClick={this.handleItemClick}
         mobile={false}
        />
```

Any help will be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

As Diesel suggested I tried:

```
<GenericIsUserLoggedInLink
 isHomeButton={true}
 route="/"
 name='home'
 active={activeItem}
 onClick={(e) => this.handleItemClick(e, { name })}
 mobile={false}
/>
```

And then in my function that renders the links:

```
function currentNav(route, name, active) {

  console.log("active ", active);
  console.log("name ", name);


  return (
    <Link href={route}>
      <Menu.Item
       key={name}
       name={name}
       active={active === name}
       >
      </Menu.Item>
     </Link>
  );

 }
```

But no dice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onClick={handleItemClick}` Is not sent a second argument. So your second object is undefined. Therefore your `secondObject.name` is also undefined.

Your error says that the second argument is undefined... nothing is being passed.

Check out the docs on [handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

There is this example:

`<button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>`

Try:

`onClick={(e) => this.handleItemClick(e, {name})}`

You could also rewrite your handleItemClick to not have the second argument be an object and just pass the name string directly.

Comment: I made an update to my question to show the update. Is that what you meant? It didn't work though.

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer after you probably saw the initial one. I made a change to `currentNav` after re-reading your question. That's the one that needs to be modified I think. You changed the GenericIsUserLoggedInLink. I'm just trying to fix the original call in `currentNav` where you had the comments. I do suggest reading those docs, event handler only passes one argument. The Event. You need to include an arrow function to add any more arguments (Unless Semantic-UI is different).

Comment: Adding `onClick={(e) => handleItemClick(e, { name })}` to the ` `<Menu.Item/>` tag inside the `currentNav ` worked,  but I noticed later at times the changing of the route/page occurs but the updating of the active state on the link component does not.  Do you have any ideas as why that would occur?